# ClusterBootstrap::clusbootglm() taking long time to run

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, replicate

I am using the clusbootglm() function from the ClusterBootstrap package. It is taking an unusually long amount of time to run this. The dataframe only contains 900 rows and 4 columns.

```
clusfunc <- function(df1) {
  mod1 <- clusbootglm(y ~ treat + u, data = 
df1, clusterid = group, family = gaussian, B = 900)
  coef(mod1)[[2]]
}

betasclustered <- replicate(1000, clusfunc(df1))
```

Here is [the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ClusterBootstrap/ClusterBootstrap.pdf) for this function.

Running one iteration of the function takes about a second. However, running 1000 is taking way longer than 1000 seconds. Do you have any advice? Should I write a different function myself instead of using the clusbootglm() function?

Comment: hmmm why do you need to run this bootstrap 1000 times on the same dataset? I am asking because there might be an easier to way calculate what you need

Comment: It's part of an assignment for my econometrics class. So there likely is an easier way, but unfortunately I need to do it like this.

Comment: what is the exact assignment question? Because in the function clusbootglm, when you set B=900 you are doing 900 bootstraps. Then you repeat this 900 bootstraps 1000 times?

Comment: doesn't quite make sense to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the clusbootglm(), I can use the following function. I have tested it, and this only takes a few seconds to iterate 1000 times. It is still unclear to me why clusbootglm() took so long to run (over 45 minutes), but this is a good alternative.

```
getclusteredsamplecoef <- function(df1) {
  sample <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  nest(df1 = -group) %>%  
  ungroup() %>% 
  sample_n(180, replace = TRUE) %>% 
  unnest(df1)
  model <- lm(y ~ treat + u, sample)
  return(model$coefficients[[2]])
}
```

It is worth noting that this is not exactly the same as clusbootglm() because I run a linear model instead of a generalized linear model. This could be changed by using glm() or lm_robust() in place of lm() in the function.

Setting n=180 yields 180 groups. In my sample, there are 5 individuals within each group, so this yields 900 observations. If you wanted to get a certain number of observations, take this number and divide it by the number within each group, and use the result as the input to sample_n().